# Application of higher-order function in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, higher-order-functions

> If \$f\$ is a numerical function and \$n\$ is a positive integer, then
>   we can form the \$n\$th repeated application of \$f\$, which is
>   defined to be the function whose value at \$x\$ is
>   \$f(f(...(f(x))...))\$. For example, if \$f\$ adds 1 to its argument,
>   then the \$n\$th repeated application of \$f\$ adds \$n\$. Write a
>   function that takes as inputs a function \$f\$ and a positive integer
>   \$n\$ and returns the function that computes the \$n\$th repeated
>   application of \$f\$:
>
> ```
> def repeated(f, n):
>     """Return the function that computes the nth application of f.
>
>     f -- a function that takes one argument
>     n -- a positive integer
>
>     >>> repeated(square, 2)(5)
>     625
>     >>> repeated(square, 4)(5)
>     152587890625
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```

Below is the solution:

```
from operator import mul

def repeated(f, n):
    """Return the function that computes the nth application of f.

    f -- a function that takes one argument
    n -- a positve integer

    >>> repeated(square, 2)(5)
    625
    >>> repeated(square, 4)(5)
    152587890625
    """
    def g(x):
        i = 1
        while i <= n:
            x, i = f(x), i + 1
        return x
    return g


def square(x):
    return mul(x, x)

print(repeated(square,4)(2))
```

I've tested it and it looks fine.

Can I optimise this code better? Do you think I can use better names instead of `i` & `g`?

Comment: Agreed. +1 for the doc string.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice docstring.

Your loop is too complicated, and not idiomatic Python.  Use `range(n)` to repeat `n` times:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    """Docstring here"""
    def g(x):
        for _ in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return g
```

Your `repeated()` function works fine for functions that accept a single argument, like `square(x)` (which could just be written `x * x`, by the way).  However, it fails for higher-arity functions, such as

```
def fib_iter(a, b):
    return b, a + b
```

To handle multi-argument functions…

```
def repeated(f, n):
    """Docstring here"""
    def g(*x):
        for _ in range(n):
            x = f(*x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else f(x)
        return x 
    return g
```

However, there is a bug in that: `repeated(square, 0)(2)` would return a tuple `(2,)` rather than an int `2`.  To work around that special case…

```
def repeated(f, n):
    """Docstring here"""
    def g(*x):
        for _ in range(n):
            x = f(*x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else f(x)
        return x

    def unpack(*x):
        result = g(*x)
        if isinstance(result, tuple) and len(result) == 1:
            return result[0]
        else:
            return result

    return unpack
```

Comment: The challenge itself states f is a function that takes only one numerical argument.

Comment: @200_success What is *x in `def g(*x)`, is it a pointer?

Comment: In `def g(*x)`, the `*` operator lets `g` [accept arbitrary arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) — `x` in this case will be a list containing any and all arguments. In `f(*x)`, the `*` operator has the inverse effect of [unpacking the argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) — instead of calling `f` with a single argument that is a list, let the first element of the list be the first argument, the second element of the list be the second argument, etc.

Comment: @200_success Do you think this `x = f(*x)` will work? If i have `print(repeated(add3, 4)(1, 2, 3))` where `def add3(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z` ? i see this error, becasue we are passing tuple `x = f(*x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else f(x)
TypeError: add3() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Repeating only makes sense when the function that is being called repeatedly returns as many values as it accepts. Your `add3(x, y, z)` returns a single scalar, so it is not repeatable.

Comment: @200_success In this example, `def fib_iter(a, b): return b, a + b`, I was just wondering How `x = f(*x)` is working? Because argument that is being passed(x) is tuple and (a, b) are two seperate names?

Comment: @200_success this is what am trying to say: `>>> x = (1, 2, 3)
>>> def display(x, y, z):
 print(x)
 print(y)
 print(z)

 
>>> display(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    display(x)
TypeError: display() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
>>> `

Comment: @200_success Ah `display(*x)` is doing the magic!!!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I feel that the functional way, involving `lambda` and `reduce`, could be mentioned:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    return lambda seed: reduce(lambda x, _: f(x), range(n), seed)

assert repeated(lambda x: x*x, 4)(5) == 152587890625
```

Although not especially pythonic, it is rather concise.